# Change the html layout generated by EditorForModel without having 2 views

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, editorformodel

I render my ViewModel with

Create.cshtml:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create","TestTemplate")) {      

    @Html.EditorForModel()
}
```

I do not like the output content because all the divs are one  below the other. What if I want a horizontal layout where one div floats lefthandside to the other div?

How can I modify such layout changes using the EditorForModel() helper when there is no html in my Create.cshtml view ?

UPDATE:

Why do I have to create TWO views. In the one I call @Html.EditorForModel() in the other EditorTemplate-view I do all the layout stuff which I could also do within the first view via EditorFor( x => x....) ??? This seems strange to me.

Comment: Editor templates: http://www.google.com/search?q=Razor+Editor+templates

Comment: @Simon I rephrased my question.

Comment: EditorTemplates allow you to re-use the layout for the same model if you need to. It saves you manually writing `@Html.EditorFor(x => x...)`, `@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x...)` over and over again for the same model.

Comment: Have you tried Object.cshtml? Check it out here https://github.com/MattHoneycutt/Fail-Tracker/tree/master/FailTracker.Web/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create an [EditorTemplate](http://coding-in.net/asp-net-mvc-3-how-to-use-editortemplates/). Basically create a new folder called `EditorTemplates` in `~/Views/Shared` and then create a new view within that folder that has the name of your model, e.g. `Template.cshtml` or whatever.

When you call `@Html.EditorForModel()` it will use this view as the template.

Comment: seems I have to rephrase my question then. Please see updated question.

Answer (score 0):

The question is pretty old, but to my eyes there is another approach that should be mentioned. Although MVC is not MVVM try to think a little more in that pattern. Since the generated HTML is nothing more than the content of a page it will be used like a view model in the browser. It is not the job of HTML to Format your page. Try to modify the layout of your page by using CSS which will be used to render the view in the browser.

Just use a CSS selectors like the following to change the layout of your form, the input elements or just a specific input element:

```
form { your CSS here }
form input { your CSS here }
form input[name="NameOfInput"] { your CSS here }
```

In these days the power of CSS is nearly unlimited: Let your items flow left, right or alternating and so on ;-) You won't need to create two views either.